# custom colour palette iris picker wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I wanna change default color palettes with a function in wordpress.

[This is the hierarchy of the elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sm2c.png)

and this is my function

```js
function meta_boxes_color()  {
?>
    <script>


    jQuery('.iris-palette-container').each(function(){
        jQuery(this).wpColorPicker({

            change: function(event, ui){},

            clear: function() {},

            hide: true,
   
            palettes: ['#444444','#ff2255','#559999','#99CCFF','#00c1e8','#F9DE0E','#111111','#EEEEDD']
        });


    </script>
<?php
}
```

but don't work.

What am I doing wrong? 
Can someone help me?
Thank you